# I want to access label value in code behind page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to access label value in code behind page.

```cs
int a = int.Parse(Label5.Text);
if (a <= 10)
{
    Label5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}

<asp:Label CssClass="txtStock" ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pquant") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I'm not able to access `Label5` in code behind page as it doesn't exist.
I want to fetch `Label5` value and store it in a variable.
`Label5` is taken inside datalist control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `Label5` in codebehind because it's part of a datacontrol like `FormView`, `GridView`, `Repeater` or someting. So this `Label` doesn't exist only once - it exists in every item of your data control.

If you want to set your `BackColor` dynamicly you can do it in the Databinding method (e.g. `GridView`)

```
protected void YourGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label Label5 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label5");
        if (int.Parse(Label5.Text) <= 10)
        {
            Label5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

or do directly in the `Label`:

```
<asp:Label CssClass="txtStock" ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pquant") %>'
BackColor='<%# int.Parse(Eval("Pquant")) <= 10 ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : System.Drawing.Color.Black %>' 
></asp:Label>
```